# Problemas con FPDF PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Básicamente necesito crear una parte del texto de una multicell en negrita

necesito:

```
$pdf->MultiCell(0,3,utf8_decode("**Date:** $hoy
**Time:** $time
**Product:** $producto"));
```

Pero no se como lo puedo logar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259294/any-suggestion-how-to-display-the-portion-of-a-text-bold-inside-a-multicell-n-fp

Comment: Buenas @Lithorell gracias por tu tiempo, eso lo había visto pero no lo acabo de entender por ello he abierto el post aquí

Answer (score 0):

Debes asignar el formato de fuente antes, por ejemplo:

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
```

- El primer parámetro es el nombre de fuente.
- **El segundo parámetro 'B' es para que la fuente sea negrita.**
- El tercer parámetro es el tamaño de fuente.

En la linea siguiente al Multicell usas la misma sentencia para volver a la fuente que quieres usar en el resto del documento.
Espero te sirva. Saludos.